# Spark RDD Or SQL operations to compute conditional counts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

As a bit of background, I'm trying to implement the [Kaplan-Meier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator) in Spark.  In particular, I assume I have a data frame/set with a `Double` column denoted as `Data` and an `Int` column named `censorFlag` (`0` value if censored, `1` if not, prefer this over `Boolean` type).

Example:

```
val df = Seq((1.0, 1), (2.3, 0), (4.5, 1), (0.8, 1), (0.7, 0), (4.0, 1), (0.8, 1)).toDF("data", "censorFlag").as[(Double, Int)]
```

Now I need to compute a column `wins` that counts instances of each `data` value. I achieve that with the following code:

```
val distDF = df.withColumn("wins", sum(col("censorFlag")).over(Window.partitionBy("data").orderBy("data")))
```

The problem comes when I need to compute a quantity called `atRisk` which counts, for each value of `data`, the number of `data` points that are greater than or equal to it (a cumulative filtered count, if you will).

The following code works:

```
// We perform the counts per value of "bins". This is an array of doubles
val bins = df.select(col("data").as("dataBins")).distinct().sort("dataBins").as[Double].collect 
val atRiskCounts = bins.map(x => (x, df.filter(col("data").geq(x)).count)).toSeq.toDF("data", "atRisk")
// this works:
atRiskCounts.show
```

However, the use case involves deriving `bins` from the column `data` *itself*, which I'd rather leave as a single column data set (or RDD at worst), but certainly not local array. But this doesn't work:

```
// Here, 'bins' rightfully come from the data itself.
val bins = df.select(col("data").as("dataBins")).distinct().as[Double]
val atRiskCounts = bins.map(x => (x, df.filter(col("data").geq(x)).count)).toSeq.toDF("data", "atRisk")
// This doesn't work -- NullPointerException
atRiskCounts.show
```

Nor does this:

```
// Manually creating the bins and then parallelizing them.
val bins = Seq(0.7, 0.8, 1.0, 3.0).toDS
val atRiskCounts = bins.map(x => (x, df.filter(col("data").geq(x)).count)).toDF("data", "atRisk")
// Also fails with a NullPointerException
atRiskCounts.show
```

Another approach that *does* work, but is also not satisfactory from a parallelization perspective is using `Window`:

```
// Do the counts in one fell swoop using a giant window per value.
val atRiskCounts = df.withColumn("atRisk", count("censorFlag").over(Window.orderBy("data").rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))).groupBy("data").agg(first("atRisk").as("atRisk"))
// Works, BUT, we get a "WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation." 
atRiskCounts.show
```

This last solution isn't useful as it ends up shuffling my data to a single partition (and in that case, I might as well go with Option 1 tha works).

The successful approaches are fine except that the bins are not parallel, which is something I'd really like to keep if possible.  I've looked at `groupBy` aggregations, `pivot` type of aggregations, but none seem to make sense.

My question is: is there any way to compute `atRisk` column in a distributed way?  Also, why do I get a `NullPointerException` in the failed solutions?

***EDIT PER COMMENT***:

I didn't originally post the `NullPointerException` as it didn't seem to include anything useful.  I'll make a note that this is Spark installed via homebrew on my Macbook Pro (Spark version 2.2.1, standalone localhost mode).

```
                18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class <root>.package on REPL class server at spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes
            java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 36: spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes/<root>/package.class
                at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
                at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
                at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:327)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.org$apache$spark$repl$ExecutorClassLoader$$getClassFileInputStreamFromSparkRPC(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:90)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClassLocally(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:162)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:80)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                . . . .
            18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class <root>.scala on REPL class server at spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes
            java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 36: spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes/<root>/scala.class
                at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
                at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
                at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:327)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.org$apache$spark$repl$ExecutorClassLoader$$getClassFileInputStreamFromSparkRPC(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:90)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClassLocally(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:162)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:80)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                . . .
            18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class <root>.org on REPL class server at spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes
            java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 36: spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes/<root>/org.class
                at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
                at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
                at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:327)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.org$apache$spark$repl$ExecutorClassLoader$$getClassFileInputStreamFromSparkRPC(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:90)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClassLocally(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:162)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:80)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                . . .
            18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class <root>.java on REPL class server at spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes
            java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 36: spark://10.37.109.111:53360/classes/<root>/java.class
                at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
                at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
                at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
                at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:327)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.org$apache$spark$repl$ExecutorClassLoader$$getClassFileInputStreamFromSparkRPC(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:90)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClassLocally(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:162)
                at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:80)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                . . .
            18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 55.0 (TID 432)
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:62)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2889)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1301)
                at $line124.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at $line124.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
                at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            18/03/12 11:41:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 55.0 (TID 432, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:62)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2889)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1301)
                at $line124.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at $line124.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
                at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)

            18/03/12 11:41:00 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 55.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
            org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 55.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 55.0 (TID 432, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:62)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2889)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1301)
                at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
                at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)

            Driver stacktrace:
              at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
              at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
              at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
              at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
              ... 50 elided
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
              at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:62)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2889)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1301)
              at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
              at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
              at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
              at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
              at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
              at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
              at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
              at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
              at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
              at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My best guess is that the line `df("data").geq(x).count` might be the part that barfs as not every node may have `x` and thus a null pointer?

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace for the `NullPointerException`? I don't spot anything right away (not to say someone else won't), but a stacktrace might help narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this so the syntax may be goofy, but I would do a series of joins:

I believe your first statement is equivalent to this--for each `data` value, count how many `wins` there are:

```
val distDF = df.groupBy($"data").agg(sum($"censorFlag").as("wins"))
```

Then, as you noted, we can build a dataframe of the bins:

```
val distinctData = df.select($"data".as("dataBins")).distinct()
```

And then join with a `>=` condition:

```
val atRiskCounts = distDF.join(distinctData, distDF.data >= distinctData.dataBins)
  .groupBy($"data", $"wins")
  .count()
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but like @Ramesh 's solution, it is backwards-- you need to flip the join in order to do the counts _on_ the data, and not the bins. I.e. the line should be: `val atRiskCounts = bins.join(df, bins("dataBins") <= df("data")).groupBy("dataBins").count().withColumnRenamed("count", "atRisk")` . But this works otherwise like a charm!  I haven't tested a comparison of this vs other solution but this seems like the right one for now. Will update with larger tests and accept soon.

Answer (score 1):

**When there is a requirement as yours to check a value in a column with all the rest of the values in that column, collection is the most important. And when there is requirement to check with all the values then it is certain that all the data of that column need to be accumulated in one executor or driver**. You cannot avoid the step when there is a requirement as yours.

Now the main part is how you define the rest of the steps to benefit from the parallelization of spark. I would suggest you to `broadcast` the *collected set* (as its distinct data of one column only so they must not be huge) and use a `udf` function for checking the `gte` condition as below

firstly *you can optimize the collection step of yours* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val collectedData = df.select(sort_array(collect_set("data"))).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]]
```

Then you `broadcast` the *collected set*

```
val broadcastedArray = sc.broadcast(collectedData)
```

Next step is to define a `udf` function and check the `gte` condition and return `counts`

```
def checkingUdf = udf((data: Double)=> broadcastedArray.value.count(x => x >= data))
```

and use it as

```
distDF.withColumn("atRisk", checkingUdf(col("data"))).show(false)
```

So that finally you should have

```
+----+----------+----+------+
|data|censorFlag|wins|atRisk|
+----+----------+----+------+
|4.5 |1         |1   |1     |
|0.7 |0         |0   |6     |
|2.3 |0         |0   |3     |
|1.0 |1         |1   |4     |
|0.8 |1         |2   |5     |
|0.8 |1         |2   |5     |
|4.0 |1         |1   |2     |
+----+----------+----+------+
```

I hope thats the required `dataframe`

Comment: Thank you kindly for the suggestion!  While this is something I explored as well (but forgot to mention), this is actually the opposite of what I'd want, as I want the `atRisk` column to count how many `data` instances are `geq` than each point in `broadcastedArray`, not the other way around (i.e. the value `0.7` would have _7_ at risk vs your 6, since you're missing the extra 0.8).  I'm trying to think of how to make this the inverse, but it looks like @hoyland 's response seems the easiest.

Comment: the 6 at risk for 0.7 data value is because I collected as set and in a set duplicates are counted as one. Instead if you use collect_array then you shall get 7 . did you get it? And if you seek for easy solution as hoyland has suggested then go for it. The choice is always yours. But be careful that there are multiple groupBy and aggregations and a join too which needs a lot of shufflings. So always test them before you choose. You might find better solution yourself too :)

Comment: The problem with that fix is that you're essentially broadcasting the entire data column, which would be expensive.  However, using your broadcasted array of distinct values, you can use the line I had my "failed solution" : `broadcastedArray.map(x => (x, df.filter(col("data").geq(x)).count)).toDF("data", "atRisk")` This works exactly as desired, so thank you!  Now I just have to figure out which is faster on larger data sets. Will post a comparison later.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above examples (albeit not the most rigorously!), and it seems the left `join` works best in general.

The data:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs._
val df = logNormalRDD(sc, 1, 3.0, 10000, 100).zip(uniformRDD(sc, 10000, 100).map(x => if(x <= 0.4) 1 else 0)).toDF("data", "censorFlag").withColumn("data", round(col("data"), 2))
```

The join example:

```
def runJoin(sc: SparkContext, df:DataFrame): Unit = {
  val bins = df.select(col("data").as("dataBins")).distinct().sort("dataBins")
  val wins = df.groupBy(col("data")).agg(sum("censorFlag").as("wins"))
  val atRiskCounts = bins.join(df, bins("dataBins") <= df("data")).groupBy("dataBins").count().withColumnRenamed("count", "atRisk")
  val finalDF = wins.join(atRiskCounts, wins("data") === atRiskCounts("dataBins")).select("data", "wins", "atRisk").sort("data")
  finalDF.show
}
```

The broadcast example:

```
def runBroadcast(sc: SparkContext, df: DataFrame): Unit = {
  val bins = df.select(sort_array(collect_set("data"))).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]]
  val binsBroadcast = sc.broadcast(bins)
  val df2 = binsBroadcast.value.map(x => (x, df.filter(col("data").geq(x)).select(count(col("data"))).as[Long].first)).toDF("data", "atRisk")
  val finalDF = df.groupBy(col("data")).agg(sum("censorFlag").as("wins")).join(df2, "data")
  finalDF.show
  binsBroadcast.destroy
}
```

And the testing code:

```
var start = System.nanoTime()
runJoin(sc, sampleDF)
val joinTime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)

start = System.nanoTime()
runBroadcast(sc, sampleDF)
val broadTime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

I ran this code for different sizes of the random data, provided manual `bins` arrays (some very granular, 50% of original distinct data, some very small, 10% of original distinct data), and consistently it seems the `join` approach is the fastest (although both arrive at the same solution, so that is a plus!).

On average I find that the smaller the bin array, the better `broadcast` approach works, but `join` doesn't seem too affected.  If I had more time/resource to test this, I'd run lots of simulations to see what the average run time looks like, but for now I'll accept @hoyland's solution.

Still have not sure why the original approach didn't work, so open to comments on that.

Kindly let me know of any issues in my code, or improvements! Thank you both :)